# Display specific array in x axis d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to display the days of a specific month in the X axis of my LineChart.
At this moment it's showing only the first date of each month: 01-09 & 01-10. I just want to display one month at a time and add all the date of that month on the x axis.

JSON:

```
[{
"month": "september",
"detail": [{
    "date": "01-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "02-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "03-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "04-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "05-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "06-09",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "07-09",
    "value": 0
   }]
},
{
"month": "october",
"detail": [{
    "date": "01-10",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": "02-10",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "03-10",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "04-10",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "05-10",
    "value": 5
}, {
    "date": "07-10",
    "value": 10
}]
}
```

this is how I set the scale and the x axis:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {return [d.detail[0].date];}))
    .rangeBands([50, width - 20], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");
```

Note: Im trying to make a LineChart where the user can select a specific month and display it on the LineChart.

Comment: It's not very clear for me?  to you want tthe axes tick to show the value ? or the day ? why do you want to attach the value to the axis ?

Comment: i want to show on the X axis the days of the month. by value i meant days of the month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your domain. Right now, your domain:

```
.domain(data.map(function(d) {return [d.detail[0].date];}))
```

Is returning this array:

```
[["01-09"],["01-10"]]
```

Which won't work for you:

> I just want to display one month at a time and add all the date of the month on the X axis

So, this is what you want for showing September:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data[0].detail.map(function(d) {return d.date;}))
    .rangeBands([0, 500], 1);
```

And, for showing October:

```
.domain(data[1].detail.map(function(d) {return d.date;}))
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = [{
    "month": "september",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "02-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "06-09",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-09",
        "value": 0
    }]
}, {
    "month": "october",
    "detail": [{
        "date": "01-10",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "02-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "03-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "04-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "05-10",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "07-10",
        "value": 10
    }]
}];

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data[0].detail.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
    }))
    .rangeBands([0, 440], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,120)")
    .call(xAxis);
```

```css
path, line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape - rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="450"></svg>
```